# DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node'

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, salesforcedx, lwc-dom

Getting Below error in the console **Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node.
at HTMLDivElement.insertBefore**

**JS Code**

```
handleChangeLocation(event) {
        // console.log('11' + event.currentTarget.checked);
        var ischecked = event.currentTarget.checked;
        let checkboxes = this.template.querySelectorAll('[data-type ="location"]');
        for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
            checkboxes[i].checked = false;
        }
        this.template.querySelector('[data-programlocationid = ' + event.currentTarget.dataset.programlocationid + ']').checked = true;
        if (ischecked == false) {
            this.template.querySelector('[data-programlocationid = ' + event.currentTarget.dataset.programlocationid + ']').checked = false;
        }
        this.tempLocation = event.currentTarget.dataset.programlocationid;
        this.selectedLocationId = event.currentTarget.dataset.programlocationid;
        // return;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.programdata.length; i++) {
            var programTypesObject = this.programdata[i].subprogram;
            for (var j = 0; j < this.programdata[i].subprogram.length; j++) {
                var subprogramObject = this.programdata[i].subprogram[j];
                for (var k = 0; k < subprogramObject.parentProgram.length; k++) {
                    var parentprogramObject = subprogramObject.parentProgram[k];
                    for (var l = 0; l < parentprogramObject.programs.length; l++) {
                        var programObject = parentprogramObject.programs[l];
                        // alert(event.currentTarget.checked);
                        if (event.currentTarget.checked == false) {
                            this.selectedLocationId = undefined;
                            programObject.showProgram = true;
                        } else {                            
                            if (programObject.locationId == event.currentTarget.dataset.programlocationid && event.currentTarget.checked == true) {
                              programObject.showProgram = true;
                            } else {
                                programObject.showProgram = false;
                            }
                          
                        }
                        
                    }
                    var parentProgramlength = parentprogramObject.programs.filter(d => d.showProgram).length;
                    if (parentProgramlength <= 0) {
                        parentprogramObject.showParentProgram = false;
                    } else {
                        parentprogramObject.showParentProgram = true;
                    }
                }
                var subProgramlength = subprogramObject.parentProgram.filter(s => s.showParentProgram).length;
                if (subProgramlength <= 0) {
                    subprogramObject.showSubProgram = false;
                } else {
                    subprogramObject.showSubProgram = true;
                }
            }
            var programTypelength = this.programdata[i].subprogram.filter(p => p.showSubProgram).length;
            // alert(programTypelength);
            if (programTypelength <= 0) {
                this.programdata[i].showProgramTypes = false;
            } else {
                this.programdata[i].showProgramTypes = true;
            }
        }
        // console.log("this.after Filter" + JSON.stringify(this.programdata));
    }
```

The above error occurs when i tried to hit this method continuously, Please Let me know if am missing anything here, Thanks

This error is coming after i add the below condion in the above method

```
if (programObject.locationId == event.currentTarget.dataset.programlocationid && event.currentTarget.checked == true) {
                              programObject.showProgram = true;
                            } else {
                                programObject.showProgram = false;
                            }
```